# how to debug c++ code called from php using exec()

Tags: php, c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I'm calling some c++ code in my php app using "exec" as explained  [in this tutorial.](http://webtutsdepot.com/2010/03/21/c-plus-plus-php-and-jquery/) I'm trying to figure out how can I debug the c++ code once it's executed.
the c++ app starts and ends way faster than me using for example eclipse attach to process.
any ideas how to debug the c++ code once it's called with exec() from the php app?
I'm on linux using eclipse and GDB.

the php app workflow is the following:
get values from html form, pass these values to c++ code called with exec(), get the output from c++, then display it using php onto html. think of it as php is the controller and c++ is the model.

Answer (score 1):

Really depends on how you are using the php code in the first place. If you are using PHP to generate a web-page, where you do some C++ code in the middle of the generation of the HTML (or whatever), then it's a bit tricky. If you are using command-line to run the PHP, you could just change `$command` from `"myprog arg1 arg2` into `"gdb --args myprog arg1 arg2"` - which will start the debugger gdb instead of just running "myprog".

If you can't debug the actual application (because the output of "myprog" is part of your web-page, for example), then I would simply run `$ gdb --args myprog arg1 arg2` on a command-line on the machine, and debug the code standalone.

Or, if you HAVE to debug it as part of the web-app, you could perhaps add `sleep(10);` to the beginning of the "myprog", and use `gdb attach X` where X is the process ID (from `top` or `ps aux | grep myprog`, for example) - set a breakpoint just after the `sleep(10);` line, and do the gdb command `continue`.

Comment: I've edited my question, hope it's clearer now, I have to debug the c++ after the web app starts since the input data comes from the web app and then transfered to c++ using exec() via php